# How to generate a class diagram or UML from a json file

Tags: json, class, uml, diagram

I exported a json file from my firebase but I can't seem to find a tool that can generate a class diagram or UML from a json file. Can anyone help me? It'll be a great help.

Comment: I wrote a tool to do it the other way around, from UML to JSON, but not from JSON to UML.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I did find something on the net in case you'll need it. It's JSON Discoverer, analyzes the JSON data and generates a class diagram. Although it was a bit different from what I expected it to be but it did reduce my problem with creating a diagram starting from scratch, it gave me an idea on how to start creating one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible.

An instance of a JSON document describes what values are attached to what key's. UML class diagram is meant to show structure. A UML diagram could use a class to represent a JSON object. Using the JSON keys as attributes (with nested information as a class that it has an instance of). However Going this way would still make it impossible to define the type of the information the attribute holds. For example you might have a key X that holds the number 5. Without knowing this is a number no tool can auto generate a UML diagram for you. As the tool would need to know the type of the data in advance.

Comment: Thanks! I did find a JSON discoverer it infers and visualizes the implicit schema behind a set of JSON documents. Although, it's not the UML diagram that I expected but it did help me a bit. But if you do have any ideas on how to construct a class diagram, please do comment here. It will mean a lot to me.

Comment: @qwerty_so you are correct. I will edit my post to reflect that. I should had refered strictly to class diagrams.

Comment: it could actually be possible if the json would have a structure that the UML generator expects